# I want create dummy data with two dimensional array of objects in php7

Tags: php, laravel, php-7

I have tried to make dummy data of two dimensional array of objects this is how i tried. but it is not working for me and i get error on opening the page.

```
$dummys = array(
        array([name=>'Enquiry', path=>'/admin/enquiry-list']),
        array([name=>'Dummy List', path=>''], [name=>'Dummy Link 1', path=>'/admin'],  [name=>'Dummy Link 2', path=>'/admin']),
        array([name=>'Dummy Link 1', path=>'/admin']),
        array([name=>'Dummy List', path=>''], [name=>'Dummy Link 1', path=>'/admin'],  [name=>'Dummy Link 2', path=>'/admin']),
        array([name=>'Dummy Link 1', path=>'/admin']),
        array([name=>'Dummy List', path=>''], [name=>'Dummy Link 1', path=>'/admin'],  [name=>'Dummy Link 2', path=>'/admin']),
        array([name=>'Dummy Link 1', path=>'/admin']),
        );
```

I tried this also but did not work

```
$dummys = array(
        array({name:'Enquiry', path:'/admin/enquiry-list'}),
        array({name:'Dummy List', path:''}, {name:'Dummy Link 1', path:'/admin'},  {name:'Dummy Link 2', path:'/admin'}),
        array({name:'Dummy Link 1', path:'/admin'}),
        array({name:'Dummy List', path:''}, {name:'Dummy Link 1', path:'/admin'},  {name:'Dummy Link 2', path:'/admin'}),
        array({name:'Dummy Link 1', path:'/admin'}),
        array({name:'Dummy List', path:''}, {name:'Dummy Link 1', path:'/admin'},  {name:'Dummy Link 2', path:'/admin'}),
        array({name:'Dummy Link 1', path:'/admin'}),
        );
```

Comment: Although, from what I'm seeing, I am quite sure what's wrong, "does not work" is almost never a suitable error description.

Comment: As of 5.4 you're able to use [] instead of array() to create an array

Comment: Quotes(`'`) missing for keys. 2nd format is wrong. it works in javascript not php.

Comment: It's definitely best practice to use quotes (and will be mandatory as of PHP 7.2), but the first example will work fine without them. Just adding quotes isn't going to answer the question. That said, until we know *what* doesn't work, it's hard to say what will.

Comment: @iainn, why mandatory, will Php freak out then if I have a defined constant as a key?

Comment: @Progrock A defined constant is fine - it's the current behaviour to fall back to a string if the constant is *undefined* that's changing. See https://wiki.php.net/rfc/deprecate-bareword-strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you missed quotes for array keys

```
 <?php


    $dummys = array(
            array(['name'=>'Enquiry', 'path'=>'/admin/enquiry-list']),
            array(['name'=>'Dummy List', 'path'=>''], ['name'=>'Dummy Link 1', 'path'=>'/admin'],  ['name'=>'Dummy Link 2', 'path'=>'/admin']),
            array(['name'=>'Dummy Link 1', 'path'=>'/admin']),
            array(['name'=>'Dummy List', 'path'=>''], ['name'=>'Dummy Link 1', 'path'=>'/admin'],  ['name'=>'Dummy Link 2', 'path'=>'/admin']),
            array(['name'=>'Dummy Link 1', 'path'=>'/admin']),
            array(['name'=>'Dummy List', 'path'=>''], ['name'=>'Dummy Link 1', 'path'=>'/admin'],  ['name'=>'Dummy Link 2', 'path'=>'/admin']),
            array(['name'=>'Dummy Link 1', 'path'=>'/admin']),
            );
echo "<pre>";
            print_r($dummys);
            exit;
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Enquiry
                    [path] => /admin/enquiry-list
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Dummy List
                    [path] => 
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Dummy Link 1
                    [path] => /admin
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Dummy Link 2
                    [path] => /admin
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Dummy Link 1
                    [path] => /admin
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Dummy List
                    [path] => 
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Dummy Link 1
                    [path] => /admin
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Dummy Link 2
                    [path] => /admin
                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Dummy Link 1
                    [path] => /admin
                )

        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Dummy List
                    [path] => 
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Dummy Link 1
                    [path] => /admin
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Dummy Link 2
                    [path] => /admin
                )

        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Dummy Link 1
                    [path] => /admin
                )

        )

)
```

Updated:

```
foreach($dummys as $key=>$val){
            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($val);
                    foreach($val as $key=>$value){
            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($value);
            }
            }
```

Comment: hi how will i access the array in loops?

Comment: @SunilKumar.you can use two foreach loop if you want to access inside data . foreach($dummys as $key=>$val){
   echo "<pre>";
   print_r($val);
     foreach($val as $key=>$value){
   echo "<pre>";
   print_r($value);
   }
   }

Answer (score 0):

Your second code snippet has a syntax error. `{` in php does not define a map, or, as how it's called in php, an associative array.

Your first snippet should work, but not how you want it to work.

I guess, what you want is this:

```
$dummys = array(
        array('name'=>'Enquiry', 'path'=>'/admin/enquiry-list')
     // ...
);
```

I suggest you to read this article:
https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array.php

Answer (score 0):

Use single quote or double like this
"name" => "abc"  OR
'name' => 'abc'

Comment: Could you merge your answers?

Answer (score 0):

```
$dummys = array(
    array(["name" =>'Enquiry', path=>'/admin/enquiry-list']),
    array(["name" =>'Dummy List', "path" =>'']),
    array(["name" =>'Dummy Link 1', "path" =>'/admin']),
    array(["name" =>'Dummy List', "path" =>'']),
    array(["name" =>'Dummy Link 1', "path" =>'/admin']),
    array(["name" =>'Dummy List', "path" =>''], ),
    array(["name" =>'Dummy Link 1', "path" =>'/admin']),
    );
```

echo '

```
';print_r($dummys);
```

output like:
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Enquiry
                    [path] => /admin/enquiry-list
                )

`)

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [name] => Dummy List
                [path] => 
            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [name] => Dummy Link 1
                [path] => /admin
            )

    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [name] => Dummy List
                [path] => 
            )

    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [name] => Dummy Link 1
                [path] => /admin
            )

    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [name] => Dummy List
                [path] => 
            )

    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [name] => Dummy Link 1
                [path] => /admin
            )

    )`

)